# Android Application wait notify strange behavior

Tags: java, android, synchronization

A fragment must wait for a bitmap which is rendered in another thread. To "improve" the performance I'm displaying the fragment first, and than the image is getting pasted from the other thread. It can happen that the bitmap thread is faster, or the fragment creating will be faster (which would be better). I want to run code in future when the fragment is created, and when I can attach the bitmap to the ImageView.

So I try to solve the Problem with wait and notify.
The waiter thread tells me that the bitmap is null, but in the notify thread the bitmap is assigned to the a address. How can it be that one thread is printing me an address, but the other thread, which is done waiting (UI Thread, `onViewCreated()`) telling me that the address is null?

Code:

```
private static final Object objectWaiterForImage = new Object();


public void onBitmapReady(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    bitmapLastPic = bitmap;

    synchronized (objectWaiterForImage)
    {
        System.out.println("DHH: Calling notify " + objectWaiterForImage);
        objectWaiterForImage.notifyAll();
        System.out.println("DHH: notify called " + objectWaiterForImage);
        System.out.println("DHH: notify called null check " + bitmapLastPic);
    }
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                synchronized (objectWaiterForImage)
                {
                    while(bitmapLastPic == null)
                    {
                        System.out.println("DHH: waiting " + objectWaiterForImage);
                        objectWaiterForImage.wait();
                        System.out.println("DHH: waiting end " + objectWaiterForImage);
                    }



                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            System.out.println("DHH: setting bitmap");
                            imageView.getSource().setImageBitmap(bitmapLastPic);
                            listener.onBitmapReady();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ec)
            {
                System.out.println("onViewCreated() failed: " + ec);
            }
        }
    }).start();

    show();
}
```

The Goal is make the fragment listening for the other thread to finish, and show the bitmap. Prevent that the worker thread finish before the fragment is finished creating itself. The Reason why I'm doing it so, is that the user should not wait too long for the page. So it displays first the ui, and after some ms the final rendered image.

Comment: There are image loading libraries, such as Glide and Picasso, that load images asynchronously. I recommend that you use one of those, rather than creating your own asynchronous image-loading logic.

Comment: I habe already done it. But this is not the problem with the loading of images. Im setting the bitmap to a variable and after the notify the other thread is telling me that the bitmap is null. But it isnt